# What do numbers in parenthesis after elements respresent?

Tags: nomenclature

I have seen elements with a number in parentheses after them in literature, but cannot find what it means. What does the number in parentheses after an element represent, such as in W(100) or Mo(110)?

https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1727919
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0039602880900886

Comment: Something like this? https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1727919 "The interaction of hydrogen with a single‐crystal **tungsten (100) surface** has been studied"

Comment: It refers to the crystalline plane which forms the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [Miller indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index) and they identify a particular surface of a crystal.  (You can form different faces by cutting the crystal in different ways.)  When you see something like "Mo(110)" it means "the 110 surface of a crystal of molybdenum."

Comment: An explanation of what miller indices are would probably help a bit (even if you don't get too technical).